# Unsuccessful Import Into a Module (Creating instead of Importing - UPDATE)

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying out the `import` blocks in Terraform >= 1.5 while using a module from the registry.

```
import {
    to = module.s3_bucket.aws_s3_bucket.bucket_name
    id = "deployed_bucket"
}

module "s3_bucket" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/s3-bucket/aws"
  bucket = "deployed_bucket"
  acl    = "private"

  versioning = {
    enabled = false
  }
}
```

However, I receive this error:

```
│ Error: Import block target does not exist
│ 
│   on imports.tf line 1:
│    1: import {
│ 
│ The target for the given import block does not exist. The specified target is
│ within a module, and must be defined as a resource within that module before
│ anything can be imported.
```

Any starting point to help solve this?

Conceptually, since declaring just the module itself will create a bucket, I'm thinking that doing the import that's directed to the module would create the Terraform resources mirroring the deployed bucket.

I've gone back and forth multiple sources to fill in knowledge gaps about modules and importing but have had no productive find.

[Docs guide for import blocks](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/import) show an example to import into a module that has a local resource declared. [This one](https://danielrandell93.medium.com/terraform-import-blocks-dedcdf453f45) shows a successful import but using GCS which I've tried to adopt but to no avail. I have also tried declaring an empty aws_s3_bucket resource block but receive the same error.

Would appreciate any and all help, thanks!

---

## UPDATE

I have edited my code as @lvop suggested. `terraform init` and `terraform plan` show 4 resources to create but should show actually show importing. I get the error after `apply`:

```
╷
│ Error: creating Amazon S3 (Simple Storage) Bucket (deployed_bucket): bucket already exists
│ 
│   with module.s3_bucket.aws_s3_bucket.this[0],
│   on .terraform/modules/s3_bucket/main.tf line 25, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "this":
│   25: resource "aws_s3_bucket" "this" {
│ 
╵
```

Here's the full plan output:

```
module.s3_bucket.data.aws_caller_identity.current: Reading...
module.s3_bucket.data.aws_region.current: Reading...
module.s3_bucket.data.aws_canonical_user_id.this[0]: Reading...
module.s3_bucket.data.aws_partition.current: Reading...
module.s3_bucket.data.aws_partition.current: Read complete after 0s [id=aws]
module.s3_bucket.data.aws_region.current: Read complete after 0s [id=us-east-1]
module.s3_bucket.data.aws_caller_identity.current: Read complete after 0s [id=408810908626]
module.s3_bucket.data.aws_canonical_user_id.this[0]: Read complete after 0s [id=075a95cf921eea7668bf9224ea784cb6f326d0dcd5945d0a60cee1f19df339b5]

Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # module.s3_bucket.aws_s3_bucket.this[0] will be created
  + resource "aws_s3_bucket" "this" {
      + acceleration_status         = (known after apply)
      + acl                         = (known after apply)
      + arn                         = (known after apply)
      + bucket                      = "deployed_bucket"
      + bucket_domain_name          = (known after apply)
      + bucket_prefix               = (known after apply)
      + bucket_regional_domain_name = (known after apply)
      + force_destroy               = false
      + hosted_zone_id              = (known after apply)
      + id                          = (known after apply)
      + object_lock_enabled         = false
      + policy                      = (known after apply)
      + region                      = (known after apply)
      + request_payer               = (known after apply)
      + tags_all                    = (known after apply)
      + website_domain              = (known after apply)
      + website_endpoint            = (known after apply)
    }

  # module.s3_bucket.aws_s3_bucket_acl.this[0] will be created
  + resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "this" {
      + acl    = "private"
      + bucket = (known after apply)
      + id     = (known after apply)
    }

  # module.s3_bucket.aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block.this[0] will be created
  + resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "this" {
      + block_public_acls       = true
      + block_public_policy     = true
      + bucket                  = (known after apply)
      + id                      = (known after apply)
      + ignore_public_acls      = true
      + restrict_public_buckets = true
    }

  # module.s3_bucket.aws_s3_bucket_versioning.this[0] will be created
  + resource "aws_s3_bucket_versioning" "this" {
      + bucket = (known after apply)
      + id     = (known after apply)

      + versioning_configuration {
          + mfa_delete = (known after apply)
          + status     = "Suspended"
        }
    }

Plan: 4 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Changes to Outputs:
 + s3_bucket_arn = (known after apply)
```

I understand that Terraform is trying to create a bucket but I am only trying to import my existing bucket into Terraform. Any ideas on this?

Comment: It shouldn't be showing that it wants to add four resources, rather that it wants to import them. Can you add the rest of the `terraform plan` output to the question?

Comment: @MarkoE, thanks for looking. I've updated the question to show the plan output. I agree and for sure there's something I'm doing that's not using the module and import properly. I just couldn't figure out what is.

Answer (score 2):

To import a resource, that resource needs to exist in the configuration, otherwise what would it be attached to? The module you are using doesn't have an `aws_s3_bucket` resource called `bucket_name`, so you can't import anything to that.

If you want to import an existing bucket as the bucket for this module to manage, you need to import it to `aws_s3_bucket.this`, which you can see defined [here](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-s3-bucket/blob/7263d096e3386493dc5113ad61ad0670e6c99028/main.tf#L25C11-L25C24).

Comment: Thanks for this! I was about to answer my question before I read your answer. I appreciate the explanation!

I was under the impression that a resource would be created under the name `bucket_name` because I've been practicing with `terraform plan -generate-config-out...` Convoluted my own studying, thanks!

Comment: I've added an update to the question as a follow up to what happened next!

Comment: That's a new problem, please create a new question for that (and roll back your question to how it was)

Answer (score 0):

After trying to create my own module and successfully imported into it, I knew that it should work when using the s3 module from the registry.

I found that when adding `[0]` to the module in the `to` argument, makes it work.

```
import {
    to = module.s3_bucket.aws_s3_bucket.this[0]
    id = "deployed_bucket"
}
```

This has something to do with the `count` argument in the resource block for the module.

From the [registry docs](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-s3-bucket/blob/master/main.tf) for the `s3_bucket` module:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "this" {
  count = local.create_bucket ? 1 : 0

  bucket        = var.bucket
  bucket_prefix = var.bucket_prefix

  force_destroy       = var.force_destroy
  object_lock_enabled = var.object_lock_enabled
  tags                = var.tags
}
```

Deleted my explanation for why I thought this works -- please follow comments by @lxop for why it works.

Comment: Your interpretation isn't quite right: the `count` argument is always set to 1 unless you configure the module with `create_bucket = false`. Adding `[0]` to your import block just indexes into the sequence of buckets associated with the `this` label - it's a sequence because it has a `count` parameter. I'm not sure why TF was actually letting you use `aws_s3_bucket.this` *without* the index, though it might just be a bug.

Comment: @lxop thanks again! Would you have any idea as to why declaring `aws_s3_bucket.this` without the index prods TF to create the resource instead of importing?

Comment: I would have expected it to throw an error similar to what you were originally seeing, so it might just be a bug. You could check for relevant looking bug reports on Terraform and open one if there isn't one already.